# Start another program then quit

Tags: process, rust

From a program A written in rust, I want to start a program B, have A end, and have B normally run just like if it was manually launched from the same shell just after termination of A.

My current program:

```
use std::process::Command;

pub fn execute(exe: &str, args: &[&str]) {
    Command::new(exe)
        .args(args)
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to start external executable");
}

fn main() {
    execute("/usr/bin/nvim", &["/home/dys/todo.txt"]);
}
```

This fails. *nvim* is launched as a child and is non-working as soon as the calling program stops.

How can I write `execute` so the caller program immediately stops and lets *nvim* (or another program) properly run (even without any windowing system) ?

Comment: Does Windows really kill all child processes as soon as the parent process dies? It's been two decades since I did software development on Windows, but I don't remember this behaviour.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I don't know for Windows as I don't have any box available right now. My requirement is to have it work on windows, linux and macos. I'll remove the OS tags (for a time maybe) to make it clear this isn't a Windows specific question.

Comment: I missed there was also a Linux tag. Neither Linux nor Windows kill the child process when the parent process exits.

Comment: Currently looking at the nix package which contains a execv function

Comment: @SvenMarnach You can test it on linux: nvim stops as soon as the parent stops.

Comment: I just tried it on my Liniux box with `sleep 10`. The sleep process did not die when the parent exited. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @SvenMarnach because `process::spawn()` is setting up some pipes between parent and child. Have a `while true; echo foo; sleep 1; done` as the child, and you should see the failure.

Comment: (Or maybe read from stdin; either way, the root cause is a SIGPIPE.)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine The loop writing to stdout continues running even after the parent process died. Reading from stdin indeed fails, because stdin is closed. The child process does not seem to receive SIGPIPE though (and it shouldn't, since it is only sent to processes _writing_ to a pipe).

Comment: @SvenMarnach a process reading from a dead pipe will also get a SIGPIPE.

Comment: However, something's funny there. Launching `vim` indeed exits with `Vim: Error reading input, exiting...`. But launching with `strace` makes it work... grmbl.

Comment: Even more fun: it looks like reading from stdin throws an EIO, not an EPIPE or EBADF. It looks related to the fact that stdin is a pty... digging more.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I don't think this is related to pipes at all (and for what it's worth, I don't think reading can ever lead to `SIGPIPE`). I just looked that up, and the `man 2 read` does not mention `EPIPE` as a possible error code; `man 7 pipe` states "If  all  file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process." My understanding is that closing the write end of a pipe will simply close all readers, so you can never get SIGPIPE on the reading end.

Comment: My bad. I just did a test and it indeed just ends with an EOF. Still looking at pty documentation...

Comment: `read(2)` man page has the answer: `I/O error. This will happen for example when the process is in a background process group, tries to read from its controlling terminal, and either it is ignoring or blocking SIGTTIN or its process group is orphaned.`

Comment: Which explains both why an `os.setsid()` in the beginning the process works, and why it's not reproducible with `strace` (stdin is not a pty)

Comment: (PS: thanks for the discussion, I learnt a couple of things today!)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Thanks for the investigation – I didn't know about this behaviour as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After further discussion, we identified the actual problem: The program you are launching is supposed to stay in the foreground, so it can read from the terminal (which background processes can't do on Unix).

There are two ways to achieve this. The first, and easiest, is to wait for the child process before the parent process exits:

```
use std::process::{Command, ExitStatus};
use std::io::Result;

pub fn execute(exe: &str, args: &[&str]) -> Result<ExitStatus> {
    Command::new(exe).args(args).spawn()?.wait()
}
```

This ensures the processes (parent and child) stay in the foreground, since the shell is waiting for the parent process, so the child process can read from the terminal.

If for some reason you can't afford the parent process to linger on while the child process is running, you need platform-dependent code. On Unix, you can use some syscall from the `exec()` familiy to replace the image of the parent process with the image of the child process:

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::os::unix::process::CommandExt;
use std::io::Error;

pub fn execute(exe: &str, args: &[&str]) -> Error {
    Command::new(exe).args(args).exec()
}
```

The function only returns if there is an error. Otherwise, the process image is replaced by the new image. From the viewpoint of the shell, it's still the same process, so the shell will wait for the command you launched to finish.

The advantages of the second approach seem slim. It does not work on Windows, since Windows does not support `exec()` and friends. You will have one less process around while running the command, but the resource usage of that process should be small in practice – it does not use any CPU, and the memory pages can be swapped out if necessary.

#### Original Answer

> From a program A written in rust, I want to start a program B, have A end, and have B normally run just like if it was manually launched from the same shell just after termination of A.

This is more or less what your code is already doing. There are a few differences to a process launched directly from the shell on Unix systems, though:

- The new process will not be included in the shell's job list, so you can't use the shell's job control commands like `bg` and `fg`.
- The new process will run in the background, and the shell will immediately show a prompt after the Rust programs exits.

> This fails because *nvim* is launched as a child and is killed as soon as the calling program stops.

This is not true, neither for [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158736/8070) nor for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/terminating-a-process#how-processes-are-terminated).

> How can I write *execute* so the caller program immediately stops and lets *nvim* (or another program) properly run (even without any windowing system)?

This should be exactly what your Rust code is doing (and what it does when run on my Linux machine). The code in your answer, on the other hand, does something else: It uses `execv()` to *replace* the Rust process with nvim. In effect, the process does *not* immediately stop, and the shell remaind blocked until nvim exits.

Comment: "and what it does when run on my Linux machine" Did you try with a real terminal program like vim and not just a sleep ? Your explanations are interesting but I don't see how you solve the problem.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I don't have "nvim" installed, so I didn't try that, by I tried `bash -c 'while true; do echo a; sleep 2; done'`, and it still keeps running in the background.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I also suggested a simple solution that behaves similar to your answer in the comments to your answer – specifically, simply wait for the subprocess instead of immediately exiting. I did not include this in this answer, since it is in direct conflict with the requirements in the question (which asks that the caller program exits immediately).

Comment: thanks for the answer. An accept or not will only come after some more studies.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I adapted the answer to account for the findings in the comments.

Comment: The wording doesn't really respect the intent of the question but it's good as is (and *does* answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working solution on linux, using a wrapping ot the [`execv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) function:

```rust
use nix::unistd;
use std::ffi::CString;

pub fn executev(args: &[&str]) {
    let mut args: Vec<CString> = args.iter()
        .map(|t| CString::new(*t).expect("not a proper CString"))
        .collect();
    unistd::execv(
        &args[0],
        &args,
    ).expect("failed");
}

fn main() {
    executev(&["/usr/bin/nvim", "/home/dys/todo.txt"]);
}
```

**Note:** This *does* start another program and quit but be wary that replacing the current process implies you properly closed open resources. If you can accept having your program kept alive, you probably want to `wait` as suggested by Sven Marnach.

Comment: If this is confirmed to be the right solution, and after confirmation it was already working on Windows, then I'll clean this fast written solution up.

Comment: This does something different: the `execv()` function does not return on success, and the current process is replaced by the new process. Note that `Command::spawn()` also uses `execv()` under the hood, but only after `fork()`ing a child process. I recommend looking [into this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158736/8070) to understand possible root causes of the behaviour you saw.

Comment: @SvenMarnach My understanding is that avoiding `fork` was the goal

Comment: Then simply waiting for the subprocess would also work, and avoid platform-specific code.